# use variables inside image src flask

Tags: flask

I am trying to load an image like so:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='output/{{ file_name }}.png') }}">
```

and this is how I send the file_name variable:

```
return render_template("somefile.html", file_name=filename)
```

filename is a variable inside my python code.
I keep getting 404 errors even though my image is inside my static folder inside the 'output' folder. any ideas?

error message:

> GET /static/output/%7B%20file_name%20%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -

it seems like the string formatting fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a string formatting error

Do this instead

```py
<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='output/{}.png'.format(file_name) ) }}">
```

Comment: is it possible to use F strings?

Comment: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#python-methods

Comment: thanks for the link but I couldn't find an answer there - maybe I missed it but do you know if F-strings are supported?